# Voting to leave open a question in review queue, then manually voting to close the same question, does not work as expected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

***Exec. sum.*** :

I voted to leave open a question, then voted to close it.  This worked, but only some of the information displayed reflected my actions.

***The details***:

I voted to leave open a question.  This was accidental -- in fact, I agreed with those who wanted to close it as off-topic because it was a hardware problem.

The question was this one: 
 [Battery died, but it is recognized by the system as active and healthy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249964) .

So, I visited the question directly, and voted to close it.

Clearly, if the site software would let me fix my too-quick clicking in a roundabout way, then it was as good as telling me that I was correctly correcting my mistake.

It added my close vote to the total in the close vote tally (going from 3 close votes to 4).

But when I went back to the review queue to see the review history (https://askubuntu.com/review/close/78548) , it showed just three entries -- the two previous close votes, and my 'leave open' vote.  I was, of course, flabbergasted. 
It was as if the review queue did not think there was a separate reality outside its own  tidy domain.

I would expect this not to happen.  I would think I should not be able to see an unaltered voting history, or perhaps any history at all, if the system did not bless it.  I would even expect that it might block me, or at least complain at me, if I were to do something it considered underhanded, such as voting twice.   There are a few other things I would expect, but that's more there than here.

Now, this might really be the intended behavior, and along with this, the Community is supposed to police such things, and drive undesirable behavior from the neighborhood by shaming, down-voting, and adding brusque commentary.  So, if that's the case, you know what to do, Community

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, posts live long and complicated lives, involving a great many actions beyond /review; you can find most of them documented in the revision history on the post itself.

While it can be a bit confusing, the status shown on the review task indicates *only* actions taken from folks reviewing. Since the goal of review is to bring additional attention to posts that might otherwise be overlooked, it's important to keep track of what's being done there, in that context.

As for the post in question, it has since been closed. Fortunately, "Leave Closed" doesn't prevent this, instead merely adding to a tally that can eventually start aging away close votes if no new votes are added.